# Is it possible to use Flutter to make Android app that implemented Accessibility API?

Tags: java, android, flutter

Have anyone had the experience in using Flutter to make Android app that utilize the Android accessibility API?

Is this possible?

Comment: Have you read this? https://flutter.dev/docs/development/accessibility-and-localization/accessibility

Comment: Yes, but it is irrelevant to the question I am asking. Such as, Android Accessibility API allows our app to read the content on screen OUTSIDE the app

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible of course since it's possible with native android you can use native channels for this
I have already built a plugin for interacting with accessibility service in android and he does the job you can read contents from the screen outside with it this is the plugin [flutter_accessibility_service](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_accessibility_service) just check the example and instruction from the use